# Jenkins pipeline same job for multiple branches

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, automation, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking for a quite specific option for which I haven't been able to find anything useful online.

Basically what I want is a single Jenkins pipeline job...which is capable of building from several branches. GIT repo is the same...just different branches.

Preferably branches would get recognized by a certain name prefix.

it is a possibility? Please advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression in `Branch Specifier` to match branches with specific prefix using `:<regex>`:

```
:origin/prefix_.*
```

should match `origin/prefix_<whatever>`

Answer (score 3):

Here I am attaching an image that will built upon changes in Branches i.e. `master`, `qa`, `development`. Hope this helps.
[image: Multiple Branch Build a Job]